# Регулярное выражение для поиска ссылок php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение

```
/(http|https):\/\/(-\.)?([^\s\/?\.#]+\.?)+(\/[^\s]*)/i
```

Нужно модифицировать его таким образом, чтобы оно не захватывало `.` в конце ссылки, т.е. есть ссылка

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox.html.
```

нужно получить только

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox.html
```

Думала использовать поиск вперед, но не получилось

Comment: миожно указать, чт 4-я группа не кончается ни на пробел, ни на точку `(/[^\s]*[^.\s])`

Comment: _т.е. есть ссылка ... нужно получить только ..._ - а Вас не смущает что у вас ссылка и то что нужно получить одинаковые?

Comment: сделайте трим точки в конце да и все

Comment: Трим точки в конце не подходит, там дальше эта ссылка заменяется на короткую, т.е. был текст: Ваша ссылка - ссылка.ру. И сейчас оно заменяет на: Ваша ссылка - короткая-ссылка.ру
т. е. теряется точка из предложения, а это не есть хорошо

Comment: @splash58 спасибо, работает